# Geocoder gem rails rake geocode dont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I have an app with [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) installed. System work perfectly for one edit/update entry. I m trying to bulk geocode all objects (+6500) from my database with rake geocode:all. When i run the command nothing happen... Adress wasnt geocode. I don't know why. Can you help me ? Thanks.

**Camping.rb**

```
geocoded_by :fulladress
after_validation :geocode

  def fulladress
    [adresse,code_postale,commune].to_a.compact.join(",")
  end
```